# JQM Function works initially but not after navigating back, data-rel=back

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

Designed a popup to confirm user wants to proceed.

```
<form id=\"PCSDform$z\" action=\"example.php\" method=\"post\" data-ajax=\"false\">
<fieldset data-role=\"controlgroup\" data-type=\"horizontal\" class=\"ui-mini\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"date\" value=\"adate\" />
    <button type=\"button\" class=\"ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-phone\" onclick=\"formSubmit('$z');\">Contact User</button>
</fieldset>
```

And

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formSubmit(formID) {
$("#PCSDconfirm").popup("open");
$("#PCSDpopupYes").attr("onclick","$('form#PCSDform"+formID+"').submit();");
}
</script>
```

This works fine the first time around, but if you navigate away to a different page (one nothing to do with this form), then click back to return to the page, the function no longer works. You don't get a pop up on clicking 'contact user'.

Is this something to do with where the  is placed, should it be in the body, the data-role=page. Or does it need to be refreshed in some way due to the ajax navigation?

Thank you.

Comment: Also it's in php and $z is just a numerical variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use inline JavaScript when working with jQuery Mobile: because of its architecture it can cause problems.

You can still try sticking with it writing:

```
onclick=\"javascript:formSubmit('$z');\"
```

but I strongly suggest you to attach an event in your `pageinit` handler, like:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#your_page_id", function(event)
{
    $(document).on("click", "#your_button_id", function()
    {
        formSubmit(your_PHP_variable);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That might prove a little difficult? I have several forms & buttons generated from a mysqli results, generated through a while loop.  I could give the all a unique number (as I've done with the form id). But then that would make it hard to select the button. Thinking about it, I could use a class to select the button.  But then not sure how to then get it to submit the correct form

Comment: Use a class for the button. Then use the power of jQuery selectors to reach the form with `.closest("form")`. Or, add to the button a custom attribute like `data-relativeto="form_id123"` so you can easily relate the button and its form

Comment: Thanks.  The `.closest` selector should be very helpful!  Also, I've just read that pageinit had been replaced by pagecreate though.  Is it ok not to specify a #page_id, and does it matter if there happens not to be a button with that ID on the page? Will just ignore rather than causing an error?

Comment: If you use `pagecreate` you have to specify a page id. But in the `click` handler you bind to `$(document)` so it matters only the button id (whereever it is on the document)